# What does 1e9 means in NodeJS hrtime context?

Tags: javascript, node.js

var time_arr = process.hrtime(start);
 var time = (time_arr[0] * **1e9** + time_arr[1]) / **1e6**;

What does it mean when the calculation has to multiply by 1e9 and divide by 1e6 ?

Comment: Just type `1e9` in your browser console and look at the result.

Comment: The result of 1 * 10^9 = 1000000000

Comment: Did [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41343209/what-does-1e9-means-in-nodejs-hrtime-context/41343480#41343480) below help you? Any comments? If so then you may consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) so other people who search it could see that it has an accepted answer.

Answer (score 11):

> What does it mean when the calculation has to multiply by 1e9 and divide by 1e6 ?

It means that it's multiplied by 1 billion and divided by 1 million.

- `1e9` means 1 * 10 to the 9th power, which is 1 billion (1000000000).
- `1e6` means 1 * 10 to the 6th power, which is 1 million (1000000).

You can think of it as 1 and 9 zeroes, 1 and 6 zeroes etc.

It doesn't have to be 1, it can be:

- `3e4` meaning `30000`

or:

- `1.2e6` meaning `1200000`

You can also use negative powers of ten for decimal fractions:

- `1e-1` is `0.1`
- `1e-2` is `0.01`
- etc.

It's useful for very large or very small numbers where you don't want to count zeroes.

See the scientific notation on Wikipedia:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation